# Using random.choice() with preference and uniqueness

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, random

I have a list:

```
decisions = ['yes', 'no', 'unknown']
```

I write to a file using this list:

```
for x in range(0, 100):
    file.write(random.choice(decisions))
```

What would be most effective way to ensure that 70% of the values written are something like "unknown"?

I want randomness to an extent, but also want to ensure that 70 of the values written to file are a certain type. I plan to get this percentage from the user so it could change every run.

If I had another list that was much larger and wanted to ensure uniqueness (no repeating values, but also randomly ordered) what would be the best method?

Comment: Do you want *exactly* 70% of the values to be `unknown`, or just 70% of probability? Is it ok to get a file with say 72-15-13? 70-11-19? Or do you always want 70-15-15?

Comment: Exactly 70% of the values to be `unknown`

Comment: Ok, see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26738797/13169).

Answer (score 6):

If using NumPy is an option for you, this is quite straightforward to implement:

```
np.random.choice(['yes', 'no', 'unknown'], p=[0.15, 0.15, 0.7])
```

The second array `p` sums to one and represents the probability that the corresponding entry in the first array is chosen.

The above will make sure that 'unknown' in chosen each time with a probability of 70%.

[Docs here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).

---

If you wanted 100 choices with *exactly* 70 'unknown' entries and 30 'yes' or 'no' choices:

```
hundred_choices = ['unknown']*70 + [random.choice(['yes', 'no']) for _ in range(30)]
```

...and then shuffle `hundred_choices` with `random.shuffle`.

Comment: This won't guarantee that *exactly* 70 of a 100 are 'unknown' though.

Comment: Thanks @HannesOvrén - I've edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

To get **exactly** some percentage of the values written you could use the [shuffle()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) function on a pre-generated list that contains the number of items you need.

```
choices = ['unknown']*70 + ['yes']*15 + ['no']*15
random.shuffle(choices)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 70% of probability for `'unknown'`:

```
decisions = 70 * ['unknown'] + 15 * ['yes'] + 15 * ['no']
choice(decisions)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly 70% of `'unknown'`s:

```
from random import choice, shuffle

values = 70 * ['unknown']                # your 70 unknowns
for i in range(30):
    values.append(choice(['yes', 'no'])) # fill the rest randomly
shuffle(values)                          # shuffle

for x in values:
    file.write('{}\n', x)
```